# Properly disable touch on UIPageControl in a TabView with PageTabViewStyle

Tags: ios, swiftui, uipagecontrol, tabview

I have set up a (paging) `TabView` with `.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))`.

I would like the IndexView to be merely visual, i.e. no to respond to any touch.

To achieve this I have set `UIPageControl.appearance().isUserInteractionEnabled = false`, which in fact disables paging by touch.

However touches on the `UIPageControl` (highlighted in blue by setting its `backgroundColor`) are not passed to the `List` below: tapping on the blue area will not select the row in the `List` underneath.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is my sample code (running on iOS 14.0 beta 4):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() {
        UIPageControl.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
        UIPageControl.appearance().isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                ForEach (0..<3, id: \.self) { page in
                    List {
                        ForEach (0..<30, id: \.self) { row in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: Text("Page \(page) Row \(row)"),
                                label: {
                                    Text("Page \(page) Row \(row)")
                                })
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(page)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t know the answer to this but your question helped me resolve my problem

Comment: The same here 